# JPA - Calling Stored Procedure is slow on first run after server restarted. Why?

Tags: stored-procedures, jpa, glassfish, eclipselink

I have an application deployed on Glassfish that uses JPA (Eclipselink 2.0) to call some stored procedures.

I was doing some performance testing and I found out that: whenever glassfish server is restarted and I tried to call some stored procedure, the first call is always slow (doesn't matter which stored procedure I choose to call). but all the subsequent calls are fast. Any idea why this happens?

I checked the glassfish monitor, it doesn't appears to be the connection problem. the connection time is about 70 milliseconds but the stored procedure call takes more than 1000 milliseconds. All subsequence stored procedure calls only takes less than 10 milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

Is the call the first time you access JPA?  If it is, then JPA initializes the persistence unit when first accessed, so this may be the cost you are seeing.

Otherwise, you could try setting the EclipseLink Performance Profiler to see where the query time is being spent, or use a Java profiler such as JProfiler.

In the latest EclipseLink release there is a persistence unit poperty "eclipselink.deploy-on-startup", that will cause the persistence unit to be initialized when the server starts, instead of on first access.

Comment: Thanks James. I tried to set eclipselink.deploy-on-startup but that doesn't seem to affect the time. what exactly happens when a persistence unit "initialized" and how should I set the profiler to see this?